# In the rastercoords leaflet, how do I fix the coordinates of the tiles?

Tags: leaflet, tiles, gdal2tiles.py

I have a problem that cannot find a solution.
I'm generating tiles from a png image, these tiles are generated by gdal2tiles and I need this generated map to be in the same total dimension as a normal platecarree map.
The biggest problem is that I can't adjust the tiles to place Shapefiles on top.

`/* global L */  (function (window) {   function init(mapid) {     var minZoom = 2;     var maxZoom = 7;     var img = [       1550, // original width of image`karta.jpg`
1377, // original height of image
];

```
// create the map
var map = L.map(mapid, {
  crs: L.CRS.Simple,
  minZoom: minZoom,
  maxZoom: maxZoom,
});

// assign map and image dimensions
var rc = new L.RasterCoords(map, img);

// set the view on a marker ...
map.setView(rc.unproject([968, 800]), 2);

// add layer control object
L.control
  .layers(
    {},
    {
    }
  )
  .addTo(map);`
```

` // the tile layer containing the image generated with gdal2tiles --leaflet ...
L.tileLayer("./tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
noWrap: true,
attribution: "True Color",
opacity: "0.6",
maxNativeZoom: rc.zoomLevel(),
}).addTo(map);

```
var popup = L.popup();

function onMapClick(e) {
  popup
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
    .openOn(map);
}

map.on("click", onMapClick);
```

}`

`init("map"); })(window);\`

Arrange the teams in the right coordinates which are min_lat, max_lat = -60.0, 60.0
min_lon, max_lon = -140.0, -5.0
which is contained in the total image and was then transformed into tiles.
And place a shapefile correctly aligned with the continents.